# Tool to synchronize extents of all running ArcGIS Instances

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0

I am working in 3 ArcGIS 10.0 mxd projects at the same time and am finding it laborious to always have to zoom to the same area in all 3 projects. Does anyone know of a tool or way that I can synchronize all open instances with a single click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a Python AddIn for ArcMap that has two buttons:

- write current extent to ASCII file
- read extent from ASCII and set data frame to it

However, this would require just more than one click.

On the other hand, ArcGIS Pro supports multiple maps/scenes in a project and allows you to [Link Views](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/navigation/link-multiple-views.htm) so that is likely to be the ArcGIS for Desktop application that most easily meets this requirement.